# Grails beforeDelete() and Hibernate's PostDeleteEventListener

Tags: java, hibernate, grails, groovy

**The problem:** PostDeleteEventListeners are being invoked even for entities that I have vetoed for delete using beforeDelete().

I'm trying to perform soft deletes of my entities while also using the [Grails Envers plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/envers) for auditing. Envers works by registering a Hibernate PostDeleteEventListener. I'm currently able to soft delete my entities by using Grails's convenient [beforeDelete()](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#eventsAutoTimestamping) dynamic domain object method. The method seems to allow vetoing of the delete request by returning a false value. So here's a simplified view of what I have:

```
def beforeDelete() { false }
```

The above code keeps my entity safe from being physically deleted, but Envers's PostDeleteEventListener is still being invoked, and it's erroneously logging that the entity was actually deleted, when in fact it has not been.

What am I doing wrong? Is this a Grails issue, or can PostDeleteEventListeners receive requests that were vetoed? If the latter please explain how to detect this vetoed case, thanks.

Comment: Why do you assume the PostDeleteEventListeners should not be called in this case? I can think of a few scenarios where you might want to do some clean-up code even on a failed/false event outcome. The issue seems to be with the Envers plugin - you might have to fork/extend it to detect the false return value and then not log the event(?)

Comment: @nickdos, thanks for the response. I actually didn't assume a PostDeleteEventListener cannot receive vetoed events, if you read my question all the way through. Would you explain how I can detect that it was vetoed though? I'm actually not sure if "veto" is the right term since I don't know how beforeDelete() is implemented. But vetoing is how PreDeleteEventListener works, and I've been assuming that's how beforeDelete() is implemented, not sure.

Comment: I was responding to: "but Envers's PostDeleteEventListener is still being invoked". I was simply stating my opinion that this listener should always be invoked. It is the logging that is subsequent to the event that should not be happening. I'm being pedantic of course :-). I think you're going to have to get into the Envers code to work this one out and I wouldn't be surprised if you have to create your own local copy of the plugin with a simple fix to check for the `return false` from your `beforeDelete()`.